# ES - Searching exact matches with special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to query an ES, with the following query:

```
search_body={
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"origin.mac": "12:34:56:78:90:ab"}}, 
                {"range": {"timestamp": {"gte": "now-90d/d","lte": 
                 "now/d"}}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This query gives back all macs with any one of the substrings (12, 34, 56.. example: the mac xx:12:xx:xx:xx:xx will also return)

I already tried to change the query from "match" to "term" but the query doesn't give back any results, even that i'm 100% positive that the specific mac is in the DB.

when searching Kibana with the following query, it does return results:

```
 origin.mac: "12:34:56:78:90:ab"
```

also, tried to search with another apostrophe like this:

```
{"term": {"origin.mac": "'12:34:56:78:90:ab"}},
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you show your index mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you didn't do any mapping beyond the default for this field as a string...

Try:

```
search_body={
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"origin.mac.keyword": "12:34:56:78:90:ab"}}, 
                {"range": {"timestamp": {"gte": "now-90d/d","lte": 
                 "now/d"}}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```